# XAMPP v.3.2.1: Apache crashes when I try to add variables to a session

Tags: php, apache, session, xampp

**Problem:** Apache keeps crashing if I try to update the global `$_SESSION variable` in PHP. These are the entries added to `error.log` in case of a crash.

From *apache\logs\error.log:*

`[Mon Jun 29 14:10:34.142373 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6644:tid 316] AH00428: Parent: child process 1440 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Mon Jun 29 14:10:34.262613 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6644:tid 316] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) PHP/5.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jun 29 14:10:34.262613 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6644:tid 316] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jan 28 2015 16:48:40
[Mon Jun 29 14:10:34.262613 2015] [core:notice] [pid 6644:tid 316] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Jun 29 14:10:34.266524 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6644:tid 316] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6376
[Mon Jun 29 14:10:35.026097 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6376:tid 428] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.`

**Windows Event viewer**
[image]

**About my source code:** I have a php script and intend to add variables to an existing session. For that matter, I use `$_SESSION` and set some keys to arrays, i.e. `$_SESSION['foo'] = bar`, where `bar` is an array containing objects of a very simple class having only some string attributes.

If I do that the first time, I'm fine. If I re-assign a value to `$_SESSION['foo']` after reloading the page, Apache crashes and immediately restarts. I was able to isolate the crash to this very line, as commenting it out turned out to prevent the crash. First, I assumed my session is somehow corrupted or I use it incorrectly. But if I manually set `$_SESSION['foo'] = ""`, instead of assigning an array, no crash occurs.

Similar reports I found in the web had different error sources, so I tried a few things, e.g.:

- Run XAMPP as administrator
- Increase the thread stack size in httpd.conf
- Deactivate unused php-extensions
- Switched to different ports, etc.
- Turned off SSL

Unfortunately, nothing helped in my case.

PS: I use XAMPP v.3.2.1 with PHP 5.6.8 on Windows 8.1 (64bit).

**EDIT:** As suggested by donald123, I turned off SSL. The error persists, but I posted a cleaner log snippet.

Comment: maybe turn off ssl in your config

Comment: I turned it off, thanks for the hint. Unfortunately, the error is still the same.